# how to give horizontal paging in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

-Display  the first 3 images in 3 views on the Screen that are visible to the user (e.g. <-- img1   img2   img3 -->)
-Keep a record of what's on display..
-When a user scrolls left or right the next/previous image in the array is displayed.
E.g scrolling right once will give me (   <--  img4  img5 img6 --> )

and so on...and also img click events

Answer (score 0):

Since API 5.0 there is [PictureScrollField](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Picture_scroll_field_1204071_11.jsp) which looks like does what you need. On a pre 5.0 OS you'll have to code your own custom component.

Comment: In  PictureScrollField use array of images but i want to use horizontal paging. 3 Bitmapfield add in horizontalfield manager and when it is scrolling next 3 bitmapfield which is added in horizontalfield manager display. and scroll like a guesture touch or touch event so pls help me asap

Comment: ex: i want to like horizontapager in android ..pls help me i am new in blackberry

Comment: @moon: sorry I'm not able to help you with a custom component, because this would imply coding it from zero while I'm also under pressure of time on my current projects.

Comment: hi, can u tell me in blackberry 6.0 simulator 9800 when open that then the first tab is all and after that when we move right side then open favourite..how it possible and which component use for that to scroll

Comment: I really don't know what component RIM used for its home screen scroller (and nobody knows because RIM does not publish their sources). I would start looking at `HorizontalFieldManager`.